# Anomally increase in records of table: From Order ID 54 to 86?

Tags: django, heroku

I've a DjangoApp hosted in Heroku.

For a while it worked perfectly.

> In recent days I saw a strange "user" signup with this email:
>   "accessto@hidebusiness.xyz", name: "Access", lastname: "To".
>
> He/She signed up 2 times: first as "accessto2" after with "accessto3".

**NOTE:**

The user "accessto2" and "accessto3" didn't concreate any order. So he/she only altered my **users** table but not my **Order** table.

After that my normal record of Order was altered. Before this incident Order.id increased by 1, but around this incident it went from 54 to 86. Why?

**What could have happened? 
How can I debug this?**

> I need to make sure it does not happen again, as it seems like there
>   were Orders not saved to DataBase.

Comment: The IDs are irrelevant, and you shouldn't care what the sequence is. And that syntax error doesn't have anything to do with the IDs.

Comment: I was using the ID as the Number of the Order. So I think I'll have to create a field name order_number that increments when a new order is placed. But what are the reasons for this behaviour (the jump of the Ids)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman so this is not an error in the DataBase or the App itself??? The Jump on the Ids made me think there were missing Order records...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the incident caused rollbacks when trying to create new Orders.

Since Postgres and MySQL don't rollback the id count, the next Order got the failed id + 1, and so on.

Comment: Ty. The user "accessto2" and "accessto3" didn't concreate any order. So he/she only altered my users table but not my Order table.